# asp.net core 2.0 app publishing taking over 20 mins -- then won't load

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I have an application with about 6 Nuget packages and 3-4 local project references. The local build is fast and runs as expected. When I set up a profile to publish in release mode to local folder for file deployment, it will list out thousands of lines in build output resolving tons of packages for easily 20-25 mins.

Once this process completes, the site errors out in a 500 complaining about missing:

An unhandled exception has occurred: No service for type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration' has been registered.

I have tried to disable AI on entire application. removed all references and even disabled via the JSON config using:

`ASPNETCORE_preventHostingStartup": "True"`

waiting 20-25 for each publish process to complete is painful. but to then have it fail because of this error repeatedly is driving me mad.

What am I missing?